# Add button to UI-Grid

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mean-stack, ui-grid

In `ui-grid` I want to customize a button for importing csv file only not that drop down menu that is in that ui-grid. I don't want to change anything in ui-grid I just want to add an additional button with it. So that it is easily visible on top of UI-grid.

**Code**

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngTouch', 'ui.grid', 'ui.grid.selection', 'ui.grid.exporter', 'ui.grid.importer']);

app.controller('ViewController', ['$scope', '$http', 'uiGridConstants', function ($scope, $http, uiGridConstants) {

  $scope.gridOptions = {
    enableGridMenu: true,
importerDataAddCallback: function ( grid, newObjects ) {
    //   $scope.data = $scope.data.concat( newObjects );
    $scope.data = newObjects;
    console.log($scope.data);    
    $http.post('/save', $scope.data).then(function(data){
    console.log(data);
      $http.get('/save')
  .success(function(data) {
      $scope.gridOptions.data = data;
    });
    });
  },
    onRegisterApi: function(gridApi) {
            $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
    }
  }

$scope.gridOptions.columnDefs = [
    {name:'name'},
    {name:'age'},
    {name: 'marks'}
  ];   
  $http.get('/save')
  .success(function(data) {
      $scope.gridOptions.data = data;
    });
}])


<div ng-controller="ViewController">

  <div ui-grid="gridOptions" ui-grid-importer ui-grid-selection ui-grid-exporter  class="grid">
    </input>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have imported data from csv file and saved it in my database and then displayed the data into ui-grid. Now i want the choose file to upload (i.e. the csv file) to be able to uploaded from a single button that can be placed anywhere and on any page with or without the ui-grid.  Everything is working fine I just want a customized button for importing file

Comment: Please update the question with the code you have.

Comment: Please check I have added the code also.